# Can't downgrade to Typescript Version 3.4.3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, yarnpkg

I have added typescript to my Vue-Cli Project by `vue add @vue/typescript`, and by default it added `3.4.3` version in `package.json`.

I am new to Typescript and didn't know `SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.2.1 <3.6.0` so I updated to the latest verion **.i.e.,** `3.6.3`. Now my project is breaking due to this.

To fix this I did `yarn add typescript@^3.4.3 --dev --exact` and it updated the version in `package.json` but it still giving me `WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by typescript-estree.` due to which my project is not running as expected but on `3.4.3` it was fine.

I also removed `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` file but no way.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: what are you claiming - yarn does not work? or whatever causes this warning is corrupt? or did you even stop investigate? Is the warning correct? My guess is: it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use the following steps:

- Remove `node_modules` folder.
- Delete `yarn.lock` file.
- Run `yarn cache clean`.
- Make sure typescript version is in range of `3.2.1 - 3.6.0` in `package.json`.
- After that, run `yarn install`.

You will be good to go :)

Comment: You saved my dayyyyyyyyyy!
BTW `yarn cache clean` does the trick here :D